# How to batch upload file without using HTML file input field

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a project wherein I need to batch upload records with files. The data will be coming from an MS Excel file, and a column will be the file path of the record's attached file. I managed to do it with local network, however, I used a shared folder for it in every computer and I am only getting the IP address of the user to go to that shared folder. It would be just fine, if the system will be used with intranet. The problem is, the system should run through internet. Is it possible to do this?

P.S. I used the copy() function of PHP.

Edit: Here's the code where I put the values of the file column into loop

```
for($i=5; $i<=9; $i++){ // GET ONLY 5 ROWS OF DATA (FOR TESTING)
        $series_number = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$i)->getValue();
        if($series_number!=''){
            $date = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getValue();
            $date = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($date);
            $date = date('Y-m-d', $date);
            $issuedto = explode('/', $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$i)->getValue());
            $issuedby = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$i)->getValue();
            $q = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM tbl_employees WHERE name="'.$issuedby.'"');
            if($q->num_rows()>0){
                $issuedbyid = $q->row()->id;
            }else{
                $issuedbyinsert =  array('name' => $issuedby);
                $this->db->insert('tbl_employees', $issuedbyinsert);
                $issuedbyid = $this->db->insert_id();
            }
            $subject = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$i)->getValue();
            $original_file_name = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,$i)->getValue();
            $ext = pathinfo($original_file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $classification = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,$i)->getValue();
            $restriction = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7,$i)->getValue();
            $file = explode('\\', $original_file_name);
            $file = end($file);
            // UPLOAD THE FILE DECLARED IN EXCEL
            if (copy('\\\\'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\\".$original_file_name, 'uploads/docs/'.$file)) {
                // NOTE: PLEASE INSTALL IMAGEMAGICK
                $this->load->helper('file');
                $check = explode('/', get_mime_by_extension('uploads/docs/'.$file));
                if($check[0]=='image'){
                    exec('convert uploads/docs/'.$file.' uploads/docs/'.preg_replace('"\.'.$ext.'"', '.pdf', $file));
                    unlink('uploads/docs/'.$file);
                    $file = preg_replace('"\.'.$ext.'"', '.pdf', $file);
                }

                // Insert to tbl_issuances
                if($this->session->userdata['usertype']==1){
                    $status2 = 'Approved';
                }else{
                    $status2 = 'Pending';
                }
                $insert = array(
                        'series_number' => $series_number,
                        'date_created' => $date,
                        'issued_by' => $issuedbyid,
                        'subject' => $subject,
                        'file' => $file,
                        'original_file_name' => $file,
                        'status' => $status2,
                        'restriction' => $restriction,
                        'classification' => $classification,
                        'record_type' => 1,
                        'batch_id' => $batch_id
                    );
                $this->db->insert('tbl_issuances',$insert);
                $issuance_id = $this->db->insert_id();

                // Insert to tbl_emp_issuances
                foreach ($issuedto as $val) {
                    if(strpos($val, 'Staff')==false){
                        $q = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM tbl_employees WHERE name ="'.$val.'"');
                        if($q->num_rows()>0){
                            $issuedtoid = $q->row()->id;
                        }else{
                            $this->db->insert('tbl_employees', array('name' => $val));
                            $issuedtoid = $this->db->insert_id();
                        }
                    }
                    $issuedtoinsert = array(
                            'emp_id' => $issuedtoid,
                            'issuance_id' => $issuance_id
                        );
                    $this->db->insert('tbl_emp_issuances',$issuedtoinsert);
                }       
            } else {
                $error .= "Failed to add <span style='color:red'>'".$subject."'</span> on <span style='color:blue'>row ".$i."</span> because the file you're trying to upload is not found.<br>";
            }
        }
```

This method is for the shared folder approach. It works within the network. But when I try the copy() function with the path like 'C:/Users/etc/file.jpg', the error 'Failed to add...' appears. Is there any way to do this with the IP address of the user but you'll get it from different locations in his computer?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using and show us what's happening and what you expect to happen? On StackOverflow, it is highly encouraged to post code with your question to give those answering some context.

Answer (score 1):

According to the examples in the php manual it should work.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

However, I would encourage you to use `$FILES` and `move_uploaded_file`

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php